# How to show Alert with message using Acr.UserDialogs

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to display the long `Alert` with message using ACR.UserDialogs plugin. Currently I am using `DisplayAlert()` but the problem is that if a user touches anywhere on the screen the popup close.

So, I want to use the Acr.UserDialogs for display alert. Can you please tell me how can I use in Xamarin.Forms PCL project for iOS & Android. Also how can I capture user pressed Yes or No. If there are two button for Yes and No.

Comment: In this plugin we can show single action(Ok or Cancel) with msg(Ex. homework creation failed). Or multiple actions((Ok and Cancel)) without msg only alert(but alert can be the msg in bold latter). If you ok I can post it.

Comment: @CGPA6.4. Thanks for your reply single action with msg will help for me

Answer (score 3):

First install [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) on your solution level. To show `Alert` we need to setup `AlertConfig` & assign that to `Instance` of `Alert`.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Action OkAction = () =>
    {
        MyMethod();
    };

    btnSubmit.Clicked += delegate
    {
        var aConfi = new AlertConfig();
        aConfi.SetMessage("Homework has been submitted");
        aConfi.SetTitle("Alert");
        aConfi.SetOkText("Ok");
        aConfi.SetAction(OkAction);
        UserDialogs.Instance.Alert(aConfi);
    };
}
```

In `Action` we are using `MyMethod`, In this method you can define your logic.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
   //your code
}
```

Add below line in your `MainActivity` of Android project before calling `LoadApplication`.

```
UserDialogs.Init(this);
```